# Displaying content defined by radio button in admin panel

Tags: templating, entries, control-panel

I want to let my customer decide if they want a 2 or 3 column page so I made a radio button but now I need to show different content if they select one of them but I cant get the syntax right.

```
{% if entry.column.contains ('two') %}
   content here for two columns
{% endif %}

{% if entry.column.contains ('three') %}
   content here for three columns
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close! You can get the selected [radio button](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/radio-buttons-fields) by its label (what the user sees) or the value you setup in the admin. I'm assuming you're using the value.

```
{% if entry.column == "two" %}
    {# show 2 column content #}
    2 columns
{% elseif entry.column == "three" %}
    {# show 3 column content #}
    3 columns
{%endif%}
```

You could also try a [switch](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/switch) statement. That gives you a way to fall back to a default option, which might be useful, and a cleaner way to check for more than a couple options (say the client wants a 3 column option with some a special sidebar that doesn't really fit):

```
{% switch entry.column %}

    {% case "two" %}

       {# show 2 column content #}
       {% include "layouts/_2columns.html" %}

    {% case "three" %}

       {# show 3 column content #}
       {% include "layouts/_3columns.html" %}

    {% case "threespecialsidebar" %}

       {# show 3 column content #}
       {% include "layouts/_3column_sidebar.html" %}

   {% case "default" %}

      {# default to a 1 column layout #}
      {% include "layouts/_default.html" %}

{% endswitch %}
```

To keep yourself sane, in the `switch` example, also consider using a [`include`](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/include.html) which will bring in a corresponding layout file, depending on which layout you want.  (A stray `div` for example will drive you crazy.... consider putting your markup in separate files.)

One last thing: from a client standpoint, depending on what you're doing, an [entry type](http://buildwithcraft.com/features/entry-types) might be a better way to handle multiple layouts or if there needs to be additional options/fields in a  certain layout. (In that case, use `entry.type` instead of `entry.column` but the rest of the syntax posted above would be exactly the same).

Comment: Thank you this worked had the feeling I was close but ended up just going try and error coding and still ended up with nothing Thank you so much!

Comment: +1 for entry types. It's better to just specify fields to enter content without things like "1/2/3 columns" options. Layouts can change in the future while content usually stays the same. In other words: don't dictate layout in the CP.